# How to: (jQuery) Modal login dialog w/ ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, authorization, modal-dialog

Whats the best way to override the built in login mechanism in ASP.NET MVC 2 so that a modal dialog pops up if the user needs to login (or [Authorize] tag decorates the Controller Action)?

Ive been searching for awhile and nothing really does this

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

jQuery is not a prerequisite but i am familiar with it

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible and not too hard.

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/15/asp-net-mvc-submitting-ajax-form-with-jquery.aspx

This is from another post that I can't seem to find any more:

Yes, it's possible. Just submit the login-form using the method described here by mike bosch and return a json datastructure with the returnUrl if any.

I have created a lightweight LoginResultDTO class that i return as json:

```
public class LoginResultDTO 
{ 
  public bool Success {get;set;} 
  public string Message {get;set;} 
  public string ReturnUrl {get;set;} 
}
```

Here's a script block from my LogOn view:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            var form = $($("form")[0]); 
            form.submit(function() { 
                var data = form.serialize(); 
                $.post(form.attr("action"), data, function(result, status) { 
                    if (result.Success && result.ReturnUrl) { 
                            location.href = result.ReturnUrl; 
                    } else { 
                        alert(result.Message); 
                    } 
                }, "json"); 
                return false; 
            }); 
        }); 
</script>
```

This will ajax wrap the logon form. Note that this is the simplest implementation of the javascript code possible but it's a place to start.

Then I have modified my LogOn action in the AccountController and in the relevant places put something like this:

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
{ 
  return Json(new LoginResultDTO{Success=true,Message="Successfully logged in"}); 
}else 
{ 
  return View(); 
}
```

So this is an ultralight but rather complete version of how jquery authentication could be done in asp.net mvc.

Comment: This looks great - ill try implementing this right away and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Would you put the div that houses the jquery modal on the site.master? the problem i'm having is somehow intercepting the [Authorize] - i dont know where to trigger the Ajax call, so the Request.IsAjaxRequest() is always false. hope this makes sense

Comment: Master sounds right to me. All the client logic needs to be available to any page right?

Comment: Yes - i am still struggling with this - you wouldnt be able to throw up a sample project would you? Ill buy you beer!

Comment: If you like the answer, please mark the question complete by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a web service in your project that will validate if the user is logged in.  On `$(document).ready()` do an `$.ajax()` call to the web service.  Based on the result you can display the modal popup using `the $.dialog()` function in the UI library for JQuery.